# Retrieve image src from Local Storage in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, local-storage

I have a loop that retrieves and assignes my data to my elements in the form.

So far it works great. But how can I grab the `src` from Local Storage and populate image `src`?

Local Storage:

```
Key = smallImage1_1 
Value = file:///var/mobile/Applications/66294192-6BFD-458B-B571-89ABA5F7F7E8/tmp/cdv_photo_049.jpg
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
        // Browser supports it
        $(".stored").change(function () {
            var data = $(this).val();
            var thisName = $(this).attr('name');
            var thisValue = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem(thisName, thisValue);
        });

        // Test if there is already saved data
        if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {

            // Same iteration stuff as before
            var data = $("#formID").serializeArray();

            //only way we can select is by the name attribute, but jQuery is down with that.  
            $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                $("[name='" + obj.name + "']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
            });
        }
    }

// save url to local storage
function onPhotoDataSuccess1_1(imageURI) {
var smallImage1_1 = document.getElementById('smallImage1_1');
smallImage1_1.src = imageURI;
var thisValue = smallImage1_1.src;
var thisName = smallImage1_1.name;
localStorage.setItem(thisName, thisValue);}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="odd">
    <h2>Are there Par levels in place?</h2>
    <input name="k11" id="k11" tabindex="1" class="stored" type="text" placeholder="Notes..."  >
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="ynDropdown" name="k12"></div>
        <div class="ratingDropdown" name="k13"></div>
        <img style="width:38px;height:38px;" id="smallImage1_1" class="camera" src="../img/camera.png" onclick="capturePhoto1_1();" name="smallImage1_1"/>
        <img style="width:38px;height:38px;" id="smallImage1_2" class="camera" src="../img/camera.png" onclick="capturePhoto1_2();" name="smallImage1_2"/>
        <img style="width:38px;height:38px;" id="smallImage1_3" class="camera" src="../img/camera.png" onclick="capturePhoto1_3();" name="smallImage1_3"/>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Are these `$("[name='" + obj.name + "']")` images? You shoulde provide your HTML, example of `data` and example of what `localStorage` returns. Right now answer can't be accurate. I can imagine something like `$('img[data-name="' + obj.name + '"]').attr('src', localStorage.getItem(obj.image));`, but I suspect it's far from reality.

Comment: I see JS code. I don't see HTML code, or at least a hint how `img` looks like. Same story with `data` and what is getting from `localStorage`.

Comment: jQuery's [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) saves only `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`. You have to save images src manually to localStorage. For example, by getting all images src to array and saving it using something like `localStorage.setItem("imagesSrc", JSON.stringify(imagesSrcArray));`. And then read with `var imagesSrcArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("imagesSrc"));``

Comment: I updated code with how i save the URL to local storage.

Comment: Try something like `$('#formID .bottom img').each(function() { $(this).attr('src', localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name'))); });`

Comment: You are the man, i dont know how you figured that one out but it worked. Please put it as a answer so i can mark it. You are the man cant say enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all required images and set `src` for each, based on its name:

```
$('#formID .bottom img').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr('src', localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('name')));
});
```